# How to get the file name of a new migration file using Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, one of the most frustrating things for me is trying to get the dynamically named migration file after it is created in order to manipulate it in a [Ruby on Rails application template](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html).

The problem arises when I run something like `run "rails g migration CreateSettings"` and then want to replace the created migration file with a pre-made migration file that has default values and `null: false` etc spelled out. It is quite difficult to know exactly what the file name is as the dynamic timestamp is down to the second.

I did a lot of research through StackOverflow and online and many people kept pointing to doing a `Dir.glob` to find the file, but the problem with that is that the name is dynamically created and if I have multiple migration files in there, I need to make sure that it is grabbing the correct file to replace.

**QUESTION:**
What is the best way with Ruby syntax to get the full file name of a dynamically created migration file following a `rails g migration` call? Say that the file was created after calling  `run "rails g migration CreateSettings"`, thus the dynamic name will follow the naming syntax: `YYYYMMDDHHmmss_create_settings.rb`

**VERSIONS**

- Using Rails -v 6.1.3
- Using Ruby -v 2.7.1p83

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and trial and error, this is the solution that I came up with.

After running `run "rails g migration CreateSettings"` I then run this Ruby Code:

```
1. Dir.chdir('db/migrate/') {
2.   Dir.glob('*.rb').each {|filename|
3.     if filename.include? "create_settings"
4.        file_location = 'db/migrate/' + filename
5.     end
6.   }
7. }
```

What this code does is:

- (line 1) Changes the directory to look in to the migration folder.
- (line 2) Within that directory it finds all files with an `rb` extension and starts to go through them one at a time (the `each` statement) with every iteration giving the new filename to the variable `filename`
- (line 3) Checks to see if the filename string includes the string "create_settings"
- (line 4) If it does include that string, it saves a new variable for the file path (location)
- (lines 5-7) closes the circuits ;-)

Since there should only be one migration file for creating settings, this works. For anyone else using this in the future, make good use of naming conventions. For instance, if you add a new field for the Rails app name to the settings table, you should run the migration "AddAppNameToSettings" NOT "AddFieldToSettings". Because if you do this again and have once again have the second migration name of "AddFieldToSettings", you will have two migration files with different timestamps but with "add_field_to_settings" in the title and the above code will find both files.

I hope that my research and time can be of help to others in the future saving you the time it took me to research this.

Happy coding!